# Directory path manipulation in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, path, delphi-2007

I have the full path name of a given folder for e.g.

```
c:\foo\bar
```

Now I would like to reference a file inside c:\foo named baz.txt,

```
c:\foo\bar\..\baz.txt
```

I am currently using the .. path operator to go down one level and get the file that I need.

Is there a function that can do path manipulations, for e.g. UpOneLevel(str) -> str ? I know I can write one by splitting the string and removing the last token, but I would rather it be a built-in / library function so I don't get into trouble later if there are for e.g. escaped backslashes.

Comment: What version of Delphi? Recent version have the `IOUtils` unit, which may have the functionality you're looking for; it would be pointless to post something from that for a answer if you're using a much earlier version of Delphi. You should probably add a version-specific tag (eg., `delphi-2007`, `delphi-xe3`, or whatever applies) to the other tags you've used.

Comment: @KenWhite It is for delphi-2007, am I out of luck?

Comment: Of course not. :-) The answer might be different, but everything is still possible.

Comment: Take care to avoid calling IsRelativePath. It's broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`ExpandFileName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.ExpandFileName) function:

```
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := 'c:\foo\bar\..';
  S := ExpandFileName(S);
  ShowMessage(S);
end;
```

The message from the above example will show the `c:\foo` path.

Comment: +1. Nice job - I got a phone call, and you solved it before I could get back. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Look at `ExtractFilePath()` and `ExtractFileDir()`.  These are available in just about all Delphi versions, particularly those that do not have TDirectory, IOUtils, etc.

And before anyone says it, these work just fine whether the path ends with a filename or not. `ForceDirectories()` uses them internally to walk backwards through a hierarchy of parent folders, for example.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer is valid for Delphi XE +**

Use the [TDirectory](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/IOUtils.TDirectory) class of the IOutils unit, which have the method [GetParent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/IOUtils.TDirectory.GetParent), like this::

```
uses IOUtils;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'c:\foo\bar';
  ShowMessage(TDirectory.GetParent(s));
end;
```

**In older versions**

Look at the other answers.

Comment: IOUtils not found, I am using Delphi-2007.

Comment: The question is clearly tagged `delphi-2007`, which does not include `IOUtils`. (I mentioned this in my comment to the original question.) Not downvoting, but just mentioning. :-)

Comment: This is the best answer for modern versions of Delphi, though, so please don't delete it (and up vote!)  The risk with old questions like this is that people use the marked-correct answer when they should use something else.

Comment: @Ken, I didn't noticed the delphi-2007 tag when I wrote the answer, editing it to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at `TPathBuilder` record in [SvClasses](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-oop/source/browse/trunk/Core/SvClasses.pas) unit from [delphi-oop](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-oop/) library. This unit does not support Delphi 2007 but `TPathBuilder` implementation is compatible with this Delphi version. Example usage:

```
var
  LFullPath: string;
begin
  LFullPath := TPathBuilder.InitCustomPath('c:\foo\bar').GoUpFolder.AddFile('baz.txt').ToString;
  //LFullPath = c:\foo\baz.txt
```